# variable replacement not happening when using templates azure pipelines

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

So I'm trying to submit a parameter in to my template deployment not sure what's wrong the other parameters are working as expected is only the new one that's not working, but if i set it to a boolean value without parameters it works.

there seems to be som variable substitution that doesn't happen and i just can't figure out why it must be something simple but i just can't find it

It's `usek8s` that's not working, image from variables tab

[image]

snippet from azure-pipelines.yml when it doesn't work

```
  - template: yml/pipeline-templates/deployment.yaml@parent
    parameters:
    usek8s: $(usek8s)
    stageId: Deploy_Dev
    vmImage: $(vmVersion)
    environment: 'dev'
    targetBranch: 'master'
    namespace: $(k8sNamespace)
    imagePullSecret: $(imagePullSecret)
    containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
    tag: $(tag)
    imageRepository: $(imageRepository)
    kubernetesServiceConnection: $(k8sConnectionDev)
    dependsOn: Build_Docker_Deventer
```

snippet from azure-pipelines.yml when it works

```
  - template: yml/pipeline-templates/deployment.yaml@parent
    parameters:
    usek8s: false
    stageId: Deploy_Dev
    vmImage: $(vmVersion)
    environment: 'dev'
    targetBranch: 'master'
    namespace: $(k8sNamespace)
    imagePullSecret: $(imagePullSecret)
    containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
    tag: $(tag)
    imageRepository: $(imageRepository)
    kubernetesServiceConnection: $(k8sConnectionDev)
    dependsOn: Build_Docker_Deventer
```

snippet from parent template

```
    parameters:
    - name: usek8s
      displayName: 'Use k8s deploy process?'
      type: boolean
      default: false
    - name: stageId
    - name: vmImage
    - name: targetBranch
    - name: environment
    - name: namespace
    - name: imagePullSecret
    - name: containerRegistry
    - name: tag
    - name: imageRepository
    - name: kubernetesServiceConnection
    - name: dependsOn
      default: []
stages:
- stage: ${{ parameters.stageId }}
  displayName: '${{ parameters.stageId }}'
  dependsOn: ${{ parameters.dependsOn }}
  condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/${{ parameters.targetBranch }}'), eq(${{ parameters.usek8s }}, true))
  jobs:
```

error i get

[image]

if i remove the boolean data type and just run it with name i get the same kind of error only in the conditions row
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> variable replacement not happening when using templates azure pipelines

This is a known issue and has been reported to the MS team. You could check following thread for some details:

[Queue Time Variables Do Not Override Default Variable](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/915047/queue-time-variables-do-not-override-default-varia.html)

That because we could not use queue variables to overwrite the compile time parameters.

So, MS team recently rolled out a new feature [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script), allow you to inject data into the pre-processor phases of pipeline compilation:

parameters:
- name: usek8s
  displayName: UseUsek8s?
  type: boolean
  default: False

When we queue the pipeline, we could select if we use the `usek8s`:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a solution but is there any more info when this is planned to be fixed? :)

Comment: @Kladfizk, What more information do you want to know? AFAIK, MS team does not provide much additional information for this issue.

Comment: since the rest of them is variables and not parameters it's weird that some needs to be parameters and not variables. Don't feels like it's working as intended,  could just be me missing something as well